# How do I apply summarySE to an entire data frame to output a data frame?

Tags: r

I'm using summarySE (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rmisc/docs/summarySE) which gives summary statistics for a specific "measurevar". I can apply the function to a single column in a data frame easy enough, but I'm trying to get means, sd and n for EVERY column in the data frame, using a single column as an indicator. The data looks like this:

```
row.names   INDICATOR   V1          V2          V3          V4          V5          V6          V7          V8          V9
S1          high        5.374010    3.729971    3.980272    3.833704    5.842162    12.45123    4.443093    5.289410    6.156557
S2          high        5.038479    3.991111    4.086205    3.562861    5.456350    10.87315    5.613356    4.983482    4.533033
S3          low         5.875899    3.787800    4.673221    3.615008    7.484733    11.46284    4.854490    6.272030    8.048471
S4          low         5.725970    4.424558    4.289177    3.661384    6.465843    11.42358    4.819001    4.530732    7.691810
S5          high        5.856858    3.710087    4.540943    3.575522    6.064775    11.26261    4.424541    4.989965    5.957384
S6          low         4.976248    3.747748    3.830143    3.522880    5.099448    11.17344    4.610697    5.578816    5.388057
S7          high        5.748943    6.361523    4.220688    3.615529    6.699602    10.77316    4.271772    4.656495    6.058274
S8          high        6.140979    4.514577    3.878116    3.722885    5.279296    10.47886    5.244666    5.347839    5.211714
S9          low         4.677525    4.378035    4.639693    3.636484    6.341705    11.25809    4.452191    4.487125    7.306832
S10         high        5.262167    5.364728    4.212417    3.721577    5.611512    11.56090    5.512644    4.675201    6.656299
```

And I need the data to look like the following:

```
row.names    high_mean    high_sd    high_n    low_mean    low_sd    low_n
V1           5.214657     0.013264   6         4.13246     0.023869  5
V2           5.214657     0.013264   6         4.13246     0.023869  5
V3           5.214657     0.013264   6         4.13246     0.023869  5
V4           5.214657     0.013264   6         4.13246     0.023869  5
V5           5.214657     0.013264   6         4.13246     0.023869  5
V6           5.214657     0.013264   6         4.13246     0.023869  5
V7           5.214657     0.013264   6         4.13246     0.023869  5
V8           5.214657     0.013264   6         4.13246     0.023869  5
V9           5.214657     0.013264   6         4.13246     0.023869  5
```

I've been trying to execute the command like this:

```
data_summary <- apply(df, 2, summarySE(measurevar = x, groupvars = indicator))
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
Error in mapvalues(x, from = names(replace), to = replace, warn_missing = warn_missing) : 
object 'x' not found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We can loop through the 'V' columns, apply `summarySET` on each column specifying the 'groupvars',  use `rbindlist` to create a single data.table, create a sequence column ('ind'), and reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format with `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(grep('^V', names(df1), value=TRUE), 
         function(x) summarySE(df1[c(x, 'INDICATOR')], measure=x,groupvars='INDICATOR')))

setnames(DT, 3, 'mean')
DT[, ind := 1:.N, INDICATOR]
dcast(DT, ind~INDICATOR, value.var=c('V1', 'sd' , 'se', 'ci'))
```